# add 23hr 55 sec to timestamp object java

Tags: java

How can I add 23 hr 59 min to the timestamp object which will be converted to Date object in java?

I want to get for example 2011-12-08 23:59:59.0

As I get the timestamp from pop up calender, I always get 2011-12-08 00:00:00.0 like this. That's why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all obtain the `Calendar` instance and use `setTimeInMillis()` method to set timestamp's time.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestampObj.getTime());
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 55);
Date date=cal.getTime();
```